# Issues using SSL termination with Keycloak on Kubernetes with Ingress-nginx

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, keycloak, amazon-eks

I have tried every tip I could find on Google to try to resolve this but at this point I am at a loss.  I successfully got my web application correctly redirecting to Keycloak login page with Kubernetes, AWS NLB and Ingress-Nginx with SSL enabled.

Issue
The browser indicates the page is secure but after further inspection indicates that "Your connection to the site is not fully secure".  This is most likely caused by HTTP being used in my internal K8s network between the LB and Keycloak.  The console may show that the HTTPS connection requested an insecure resource, presumably because the ingress is fetching data from keycloak in the backend over http.

I have read the docs here https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy and read forum posts which suggested the configurations below.

I have modified the annotations below to the Ingress-Nginx service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:my-cert
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "external"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: "ip"
```

I have added the env variable to the keycloak container in my kubernetes yaml file as shown below to tell keycloak that the SSL connections are being handled by the LB.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: KC_PROXY
          value: "edge"
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
```

Also, when I try to access the keycloak admin console, I am getting the following message:

Refused to frame 'keycloak.my-domain.com' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".

I am not sure if the two issues are caused by the same problem.  I have set the following configurations in the ingress snippet to ensure the proxy is setting the correct headers for keycloak from the connecting user browser (if I am understanding correctly) and set SSL-redirect to false.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" # ADDED
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      add_header X-Frame-Options "sameorigin";
      add_header Referrer-Policy 'same-origin';
      proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
```

From what I have read my keycloak configs are correct, I am wondering if there's an issue with my ingress-nginx configs.  Based on what I have here, is there anything that stands out as incorrect?  Any help would be appreciated!